# Hide Row if value in given row exists in another table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with products and I want to hide the row if said product can be found in a different table.
So for each row of table 1 check if value in column A can be found in Table 2 column A and if yes hide that row in table 1.

I have this code I am using as base, but I have yet to figure out how to refer to the second table column 1 for checking.

```
For Each row In myTable.DataBodyRange.Rows
    If row.Cells(1, 1).Value = 'can be found in column A table 2 Then
       row.Hidden = True
    End If
Next
```

EDIT:

My final working code provided by @Vityata for anyone interested:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim tbl1 As ListObject
    Set tbl1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

    Dim tbl2 As ListObject
    Set tbl2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2")

    Dim myRow As Range

    For Each myRow In tbl1.DataBodyRange.Rows
        If Not myRow.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Hidden Then
        Dim hideMe As Variant
        hideMe = Application.Match(myRow.Cells(1, 3).Value2, tbl2.Range.Columns(1).Cells, 0)
        If IsError(hideMe) Then hideMe = False
        myRow.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = hideMe
        End If
    Next myRow

End Sub
```

Comment: You're on the right track. Now, you can use [`Range.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) method to check if the value exists in the second table.

Comment: Thanks for the hint I will look into this method :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim tbl1 As ListObject
    Set tbl1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    Dim tbl2 As ListObject
    Set tbl2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2")
    
    Dim myRow As Range
    
    For Each myRow In tbl1.Range.Rows
        Dim hideMe As Variant
        hideMe = Application.Match(myRow.Cells(1, 1).Value2, tbl2.Range.Columns(1).Cells, 0)
        If IsError(hideMe) Then hideMe = False
        myRow.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = hideMe
    Next myRow

End Sub
```

---

- The code loops through every row of `tbl1.Range.Rows`;
- Assigns a "boolean" value `True` to `hideMe`, if the cell is found through `Application.Match`;
- If the cell is not found, it gives an error, which is translated to `False`;
- `myRow.Cells(1,1).EntireRow.Hidden = hideMe` hides the row;
- If you want to exclude the `Header` of the table from the search, change the loop to:

  `For Each myRow In tbl1.DataBodyRange.Rows`

Comment: Would this not search on the header row as well?

Comment: @Tom - yes, it searches the header as well.

Comment: @Vityata thanks for the quick solution! I will try to implement this immediatly

Comment: @Vityata Been testing your code and it works as intended, but one thing I didnt mention is, that my sheet already gets pre filtered for a certain value in another column. Your code unhides the rows already hidden by that filter, would there be an easy work around for that? Thanks

Comment: @Tim - put a condition in the loop - `If myRow.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Hidden Then` and do not do anything if it is `True`. If it is `False`, do the thing in the loop.

Comment: @Vityata Yes I used If Not myRow.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Hidden and then ran the loop. Works perfectly :9

Comment: @Tim - thumbs up! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also filter the table on Product column in sheet 1  table using the values from the Product column in sheet 2. Took me longer to debug so only just seen some elements similar to answer already given

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lookupRange As Range
    Dim loopRange As Range
    Dim found As Variant
    Set loopRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange.Columns(1)
    Set lookupRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Columns(1)

    Dim arr()
    ReDim arr(loopRange.Count)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table2").Range
        .AutoFilter
        For Each rng In loopRange.Cells
            found = Application.Match(rng.Value, lookupRange, 0)
            If IsError(found) Then
                arr(counter) = rng.Value
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems like a good idea but I am already filtering my table quite heavily so I tried not using this method.